# How can i map a multi level sub domain with sub folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have the following multi level sub domains:

- **aaa.bbb.ccc**.app.example.com
- **xxx.yyy.zzz**.app.example.com
- **111.222.333**.app.example.com

And the content (index.html, css, JavaScript) for these domains are located on:

- root/**aaa/bbb/ccc**
- root/**xxx/yyy/zzz**
- root/**111/222/333**

Where by all initial domain levels point to **root**.

In .htaccess how do i go about pointing these domains (no redirects) to their respective folders? So far I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.app.example\.com
RewriteRule ^$ /%1/%2/%3/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But the problem with this code is that although it points to the correct folder, it only displays the "index.html" files all other content (css, javascript...) comes up as 404 error.

For example:

root/**aaa/bbb/ccc**/style.css

should also be accessible via

**aaa.bbb.ccc**.app.example.com/style.css

But i get 404 for aaa.bbb.ccc.app.example.com/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in `RewriteRule pattern` which is `^$` so it matches `URI`which start `^` then end `$` , means No URI and in this case it matches only  request `aaa.bbb.ccc.app.example.com/` and that why you said `index.html`.

So , change this line :

```
RewriteRule ^$ /%1/%2/%3/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

By this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2/%3/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

**UPDATE :** you should exclude the given directories to avoid looping :

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.app\.example\.com
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(aaa|xxx|111)/
  RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for code, i tried it but it gives me the following error: AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Brilliant! The only thing is that the following will only work for aaa.xxx.111.app.example.com, because of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(aaa|xxx|111)/`. I tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(%1|%2|%3)/`, but that throw 500 error.

Comment: No , it works for aaa or xxx or 111 in URI , to avoid looping when redirection happened

Comment: your right! the problem was that the url in the demo are different to the url on my site. my site has hundreds of urls like, 123.456.Z.app.example.com, 232.890.Z.App.example.com. How do i go about writing (aaa|xxx|111) so that it will allow (123|232|.....). Iv spent ages on it and cant figure it out

Comment: I think you could't match all these because %1 could not be match in RewriteRule pattern but there is a suggestion is to move all directories under main one with unique name , for example /all/ directory and make sure there then redirect any request to a.b.c.domain.com to all/a/b/c/ internally and you could be able  prevent any request start with /all/ to be redirect again